# one-to-one correspondence between the divisors of $n$ and

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Could any one help me to understand rigorously the statement from a book Elementary Number Theory by James J Tattersall
, Page $51$

"From the definition of
division and the fact that divisions pair up, it follows that, for any positive
integer $n$, there is a one-to-one correspondence between the divisors of $n$
that are less than $\sqrt{n}$ and those which are greater than $\sqrt{n.}$

Thank you!

Comment: $\eta (d) = n/d$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divisors of $n$ come in pairs: if $d$ is a divisor of $n$, then so is $\frac{n}d$. Of course if $n$ is a perfect square, and $d=\sqrt{n}$, then $\frac{n}d=\sqrt{n}=d$ as well, but in all other cases $d$ and $\frac{n}d$ are different divisors of $n$. If $d<\sqrt{n}$, then $d\sqrt{n}<n$, and $\sqrt{n}<\frac{n}d$. And if $d>\sqrt{n}$, then $d\sqrt{n}>n$, and $\sqrt{n}>\frac{n}d$. Thus, $d<\sqrt{n}$ if and only if $\frac{n}d>\sqrt{n}$. This means that if you pair each divisor $d$ with its mate $\frac{n}d$, exactly member of the pair is less than $\sqrt{n}$, and the other is greater than $\sqrt{n}$. This pairing establishes a bijection between the divisors of $n$ that are less than $\sqrt{n}$ and those that are greater.

Comment: what is that bujective map explicitly?And how to show that is injective and surjective?

Comment: @TaxiDriver: It’s all right there in the answer. I’ll spell out the definition of the map itself, but you need to extract the rest yourself. Let $D_0$ be the set of divisors of $n$ that are less than $\sqrt{n}$, and let $D_1$ be the set of divisors of $n$ that are greater than $\sqrt{n}$. Then the bijection from $D_0$ to $D_1$ is the map $d\mapsto\frac{n}d$ (which I now see was already suggested to you in the comments).