# Prove that there is a 1-1 correspondence between all of the divisors of n which are not less than square root of n

Tags: elementary-number-theory

"Prove that there is a $1-1$ correspondence between all of the divisors of $n$ which are not less than square root of $n$ and all the ways of writing $n$ as a difference of two squares of nonnegative integers."

It is my homework solution. While I'm searching this question, I see similar one :  [one-to-one correspondence between the divisors of $n$ and](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433596/one-to-one-correspondence-between-the-divisors-of-n-and) . I understand this solution and also it's similar to my question but I could not solve my question.

Can you help me, please? :)

Thank you!

Comment: Part of the question statement is missing. If it is what your linked question is about, you should clarify what part of the given answers you don't understand because otherwise this question will be closed as a duplicate. If it's something different, you definitely need to revise the wording of your question so we know what you want.

Comment: I did not write second part of question, but I write it now. I think that is what you mean.

Comment: I could see this for $n$ odd, but not for $n$ even.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n=a^2-b^2$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$. Then you have:
$$n=(a+b)(a-b)$$
for which $a+b> \sqrt{n}>a-b$ which shows that the divisor $a+b$ corresponds to the way of writing difference $a^2-b^2$. If $n$ is a perfect square, we have $n=(\sqrt{n})^2-0^2$ in correspondence with the divisor $\sqrt{n}$. However, all of this only works if for all divisors $d>\sqrt{n}$, we have $\frac{n}{d}$ and $d$ having same parity since $a+b$ and $a-b$ always have same parity. However, if $n$ is even, this cannot happen when $d=n$. Thus, $n$ must be odd for this one-to-one correspondence.